# Remove empty p tag from String variable using Java?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to remove `p` tags which don't contain any text. And if any `p` tag contain text, but not contain any parent tag, **So I am try to create a Parent tag DIV**. I am trying to 
convert from **org.jsoup.nodes.Document** to **org.w3c.dom.Document.**

Is it possible or any short cut solution?

Java code:

```
private void modifyMediaVariantContent(String html) {

    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : doc.select("*")) {
        if (!element.hasText() && element.isBlock()) {
            element.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

HTML String value:

Before:

```
<p id="Id44">see the image and see the color... ?</p>
<p id="Id40"></p>
<div id="Id87" style="display:inline-block">
<video id="Id30" src="http://Id3.qa.cete.us/117973/video.mp4"></video>
</div>
<p id="Id28"></p>
<p id="Id-1"></p>
<div id ="Id21">
<img id="img_44186" src="/129884/apple.jpg" />
</div>
<p id="Id-320046-3-21"></p>
```

After:: Result:

```
<div>
<div id = "passageContent">
<p id="Id44">see the image and see the color... ?</p>
<div>
<div id="Id87" style="display:inline-block">
<video id="Id30" src="http://Id3.qa.cete.us/117973/video.mp4"></video>
</div>
<div id ="Id21">
<img id="img_44186" src="/129884/apple.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
```

or Result:

```
<div>
<p id="Id44">see the image and see the color... ?</p>
<div id="Id87" style="display:inline-block">
<video id="Id30" src="http://Id3.qa.cete.us/117973/video.mp4"></video>
</div>
<div id ="Id21">
<img id="img_44186" src="/129884/apple.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include in your question how the HTML should look **after** it has been processed, as well as the before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following snippet:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String html = "<p id=\"Id44\">see the image and see the color... ?</p>\r\n" + "<p id=\"Id40\"></p>\r\n"
                    + "<div id=\"Id87\" style=\"display:inline-block\">\r\n"
                    + "<video id=\"Id30\" src=\"http://Id3.qa.cete.us/117973/video.mp4\"></video>\r\n" + "</div>\r\n"
                    + "<p id=\"Id28\"></p>\r\n" + "<p id=\"Id-1\"></p>\r\n" + "<div id =\"Id21\">\r\n"
                    + "<img id=\"img_44186\" src=\"/129884/apple.jpg\" />\r\n" + "</div>\r\n" + "<p id=\"Id-320046-3-21\"></p>";
            new Test().modifyMediaVariantContent(html);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void modifyMediaVariantContent(String html) {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : doc.getElementsByTag("p")) {
            if (!element.hasText() && element.isBlock()) {
                element.remove();
            }
            if (element.hasText() && element.parent() == doc.body()) {
                Element replacment = new Element(Tag.valueOf("div"), "");
                replacment.appendChild(element.clone());
                element.replaceWith(replacment);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(doc.body().html());
    }
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
<div>
 <p id="Id44">see the image and see the color... ?</p>
</div>  
<div id="Id87" style="display:inline-block"> 
 <video id="Id30" src="http://Id3.qa.cete.us/117973/video.mp4"></video> 
</div>   
<div id="Id21"> 
 <img id="img_44186" src="/129884/apple.jpg"> 
</div>
```

To convert the Jsoup document to a `org.w3c.dom.Document` use `org.jsoup.helper.W3CDom`:

```
W3CDom w3cDom = new W3CDom();
org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDoc = w3cDom.fromJsoup(doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp:

```
html.replaceAll("<p id=\".*\"></p>\n", "");
```